# operation on 'i' may be undefined

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, sequence-points

I have this code to take a string of the form `bla_2` and separate it:

```
void separate(char* str, char* word, int* n) {
    int i = 0;
    while(str[i] != '_') {
        word[i] = str[i++];
    }
    *n = str[++i] - '0';
}
```

I got:

```
warning: operation on ‘i’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
```

But I am only changing `i` via `++` operator, I am not assigning anything to.

So, why is the UB, if it is? If not, how to get rid of the warning?

Notice that in my opinion, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623114/operation-on-may-be-undefined) question handles a different issue.

Comment: @Rizier123: that won't change anything with respect to sequence points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`word[i] = str[i++];` is a problem.

It is compiler's choice if `i` in `word[i]` is access before or after `i` is incremented in `str[i++];`

Do the `i++` after the assignment

```
word[i] = str[i];
i++;
```

---

Further `while(str[i] != '_')` likely should be

```
while(str[i] != '_' && str[i] != '\0')
```

to prevent buffer overrun.

Comment: By fixing I meant in the case this wasn't UB, but yeah I got the point.

Comment: > "_It is compiler's choice ...  is access before or after_" Strictly speaking, the code can do anything besides these two options.

Comment: Moreover, this code doesn't put a null terminator in the string. I see your point @AlexD, thank you too.

Comment: @AlexD What do you mean by this, i am unable to understand.

Comment: @SurajJain It is UB, so all bets are off.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that both sides of the assignment depend on the value of `i`, however, you are modifying `i` in the statement and there's no sequence point between the two uses of `i`. According to the C standard, this results in undefined behavior.

To fix this warning, change the line in question to

```
word[i] = str[i];
i++;
```

By the way, you could use pointers instead of explicit indices, that would probably make the code a bit more readable:

```
void separate(char* str, char* word, int* n) {
    while(*str != '_') {
        *word++ = *str++;
    }

    *n = *++str - '0';
}
```

Comment: +1 for the pointer suggestion, but I am accepting the other answer because it came first. :)

Comment: @G.Samaras [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Comment: Thanks for the link, interesting!